# MS SQL Function - Query Condition Change on Parameters Input

Tags: sql-server

I am working on this SQL function below, but couldn't figure out how to make the code condition WHERE works based on the flag (@PastDueFlag, either 0 or 1 passing).

Please assume that entire query inside this function is working correctly. The only line I like to change is right under WHERE 1 = 1 "AND DATEDIFF("d", InvoiceDueDate, GETDATE()) > 0".

I like to include this condition in the query when the parameter @PastDueFlag = 1, else don't include this line in the WHERE query.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[TotalARDueByCompanyID]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @CompanyID AS INTEGER,
    @PastDueFlag AS INTEGER
)
RETURNS Float
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TotalARDue AS Float

     SET @TotalARDue = (
        SELECT SUM(CAST(GrandTotal AS NUMERIC(9,2)) + CAST(ISNULL(LinkedTxnAmount, 0) AS NUMERIC(9,2))) AS TotalARDue
        FROM (
            select i.OrderID, InvoiceID, cp.CustomerPO, o.CompanyID, i.CreditMemo
            , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),(InvoiceDate + (SELECT TermDays FROM dbo.ERP_CompanyTerms WHERE TermID = i.TermID)), 101) AS InvoiceDueDate
            , (isnull(FreightCost,0) + isnull(TaxState,0) + isnull(TaxCounty, 0) + isnull(TaxCity, 0) )
            +
            (SELECT SUM(ExtQty * UnitSell) FROM ERP_InvoiceDetail WHERE invoiceID = i.InvoiceID) as GrandTotal
                --, isnull(i.FreightCost, 0) as FreightCost, i.ShipVia, i.WhoPays, i.Status
            , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), i.CreatedDate, 101) AS CreatedDate
            , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), i.InvoiceDate, 101) AS InvoiceDate
            , (select Name from ERP_Company c where c.CompanyID = o.CompanyID) as CompanyName
            , (select first_name + ' ' + last_name from employee where tech_id = i.createdBy) as CreatedBy
            , (SELECT em2.first_name + ' ' + em2.last_name) AS SalesRep
            , (SELECT em2.tech_id) AS SalesRepID
            , o.SOTypeInt AS SOType, em2.WH_RegionID AS Region, i.Status, qv.SFOppt
            , (
                SELECT 
                    (SELECT CASE
                        WHEN CreditMemo = 1 THEN
                            SUM(qi.LinkedTxnAmount) * -1
                        ELSE
                            SUM(qi.LinkedTxnAmount)
                      END
                ) 
                FROM dbo.ERP_Invoice i2
                LEFT JOIN dbo.QuickBooks_InvoiceLinked qi ON RefNumber = CAST(i2.InvoiceID AS VARCHAR(8))
                WHERE 1 = 1
                AND InvoiceID = i.invoiceID --   305763, 304990
                AND LinkedTxnTxnType <> 
                    CASE
                        WHEN i2.CreditMemo = 1 THEN
                            'CreditMemo'
                        ELSE
                            ''
                    END
                GROUP BY CreditMemo
            ) AS LinkedTxnAmount
            from ERP_Invoice i
            LEFT JOIN ERP_Order o on o.OrderID = i.OrderID
            INNER JOIN ERP_Company c on o.CompanyID = c.CompanyID  
            LEFT JOIN Employee em on em.Tech_ID = i.CreatedBy
            LEFT JOIN Employee em2 ON em2.Tech_ID = o.SalesPersonID
            LEFT JOIN ERP_QuoteVer qv ON qv.QuoteVerID = o.QuoteVerID
            LEFT JOIN dbo.ERP_CustomerPO cp ON cp.CustomerPOID = i.CustomerPOID
            where 1 = 1
        ) a
        WHERE
        1 = 1
        AND DATEDIFF("d", InvoiceDueDate, GETDATE()) > 0
        AND CAST(GrandTotal AS NUMERIC(9,2)) + CAST(ISNULL(LinkedTxnAmount, 0) AS numeric(9,2)) > 0
        AND CompanyID = @CompanyID
        AND Status in ('New', 'Completed')
        AND SOType = 'Production'
    )

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @TotalARDue

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you have to do is integrate your parameter value into your `where` clause:

```
WHERE ( (@PastDueFlag =1 and DATEDIFF("d", InvoiceDueDate, GETDATE()) > 0) or 
        (@PastDueFlag = 0) ) and ...
```

also, you shouldn't need the 1=1 criteria in your `WHERE` clause